# Laravel UserPolicy always returns 403 no matter what

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have the following policy called UserPolicy.
I want only admin users to access/edit the users data, even though I have set the return value to true(for testing) I still get 403 response no matter what.

```
namespace App\Policies;

use App\Models\Auth\User;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;

class UserPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    public function viewAny(User $user)
    {
        // return $user->admin();
        return true;
    }
}
```

I have registered the policy as follows

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;

use App\Models\Auth\User;
use App\Policies\UserPolicy;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $policies = [
        User::class => UserPolicy::class,
    ];

    /**
     * Register any authentication / authorization services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        //
    }
}
```

The following code is how I use it in the controller

```
 if (Gate::denies('viewAny')) {
            return response('Not Authorized!', 403);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `authorize()` method in your controller and pass `User` class as the second parameter. It will point the request to the targeted policy.

`authorize()` method is by default provided by `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests` trait in your base controller.

Your controller could be like below:

```
try {
    $this->authorize('viewAny', User::class);
} catch (AuthorizationException $e) {
    return response('Not Authorized!', 403);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked, it was bugging me the entire day. Thank you again and have nice day.